# numeric_limits::max and "invalid conversion from 'int (*)()noexcept (true)' to 'value_t {aka int}'"

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, return-type, numeric-limits

I have a type defined using `typedef unsigned int value_t;` and a function

```
value_t find_minimal_value(...) {
    ...
    if(...) return numeric_limits<value_t>::max;
    ...
}
```

Compiler refuses to compile it, saying: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)()noexcept (true)’ to ‘value_t {aka int}’.

What does it mean? Looking into the numeric_limits class, the `min()` function should return a variable of the type passed to it via template typename, so `value_t` in this case. So why the code doesn't compile?

Comment: `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is a function.

Comment: @Nemo This is ridiculous, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::numeric_limits::max()` is a function, so you need to return the result of its invocation. That is done using the call operator:

```
value_t find_minimal_value() {
    if (...) return numeric_limits<value_t>::max();
    //                                          ^^
}
```

The error message meant that it couldn't convert a function pointer (i.e `int (*)()` to `unsigned int`.